# generate html select element by previous selected value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i've a first html select element which generate a second html select element using a first Ajax Function and it will work correctly.
This second html element will generate my third html select element but when i do this code for generating my third selector it don't work.
i'm looking to made it anyone could help me?

here is the code:

```
$("#SystemNameSelection").on('change',function ()
{
   var SystemName = $("#SystemNameSelection").text();
   if (SystemName === "Value1") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile1.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
         }
      });
   }
   else if (SystemName === "Value2") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile2.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
         }
      });
   }
   else if (SystemName === "Value3") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile3.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Myfile1, Myfile2 and MyFile3 contain three different html select element.
I've tried also with the .change() method and it's didn't work too.

Comment: You should probably attach some html that goes with this.  And possibly jsFiddle.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools and check the network requests. You should be able to see what is sent and what is returned in your AJAX requests. This will tell you on which side the problem reside.

Comment: show html it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure you are using a recent version of jQuery.

```
$("#SystemNameSelection").on('change',function ()
{
   var SystemName = $("#SystemNameSelection").text();

   switch (SystemName) {
       case "Value1":
           var myUrl = "MyFile1.php";
       case "Value2":
           var myUrl = "MyFile2.php";
       case "Value1":
           var myUrl = "MyFile3.php";
   }

   $.ajax({url:myUrl, success:function(result)
       {
         $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working today i try this code and it work correctly.

```
$("#SystemNameSelectionDiv").ready(function (){
$("#SystemNameSelection").change(function ()
{
   var SystemName = $("#SystemNameSelection").text();
   if (SystemName === "Value1") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile1.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
         }
       });
   }
   else if (SystemName === "Value2") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile2.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
         }
         });
   }
   else if (SystemName === "Value3") {
      $.ajax({
         url:"MyFile3.php",
         success:function(result) {
            $("#MyElementToPutTheSelector").html(result);
          }
        });
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: the #SystemNameSelectionDiv is a html div element and the #SystemNameSelection is a html select element.